# How to enable core dump in my Linux C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, crash-dumps

My program is written in C++. compiled with gcc, using -g3 -O0 -ggdb flags. When it crashes, I want to open its core dump. Does it create core dump file, or I need to do something to enable core dump creation, in the program itself, or on computer where it is executed? Where this file is created, and what is its name?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to set `ulimit -c`. If you have 0 for this parameter a coredump file is not created.  So do this: `ulimit -c unlimited` and check if everything is correct `ulimit -a`. The coredump file is created when an application has done for example something inappropriate. The name of the file on my system is `core.<process-pid-here>`.

Comment: Thanks, I executed "ulimit -c unlimited" from the terminal window (Ubuntu), then executed my program from the same window, and it created core dump. How can I make this mode default? When I execute my program from keyboard shortcut, dump is not created.

Comment: 1) `setrlimit` is a way to set the core file size from your program. 2) Or set `ulimit -c unlimited` in your profile.

Comment: Place the line in your `~/.profile`.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add `ulimit -c unlimited` to end of file and save.

Answer (score 55):

You can do it this way inside a program:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

// core dumps may be disallowed by parent of this process; change that
struct rlimit core_limits;
core_limits.rlim_cur = core_limits.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &core_limits);
```

Answer (score 14):

By default many profiles are defaulted to 0 core file size because the average user doesn't know what to do with them.

Try `ulimit -c unlimited` before running your program.