# gcc -g :what will happen

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb

This question was asked to me in an interview.

they asked me how to generate a core dump file with which i can debug.
then i said that with `-g` flag in `gcc` we can do it.

then they have asked me what exactly does that `-g` flag do  to the compiler.

i said (probably a wrong answer) that it will open up all the symbols in the core file which can be used for debugging.

can anyone tell me what exactly does it do?

Comment: It's probably noteworthy to mention that if you want to generate a core dump of a process, you can pass it's PID to the gcore command.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

That's kind of right, but incomplete.  `-g` requests that the compiler and linker generate and retain source-level debugging/symbol information in the executable itself.

*If*...

- the program happens to later crash and produce a core file (which suggests some problem in the actual code), or
- a deliberate OS command forced it to core (e.g. `kill -SIGQUIT` *pid*), or
- the program calls a function that dumps core (e.g. [`abort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort))

...- none of which are actually caused by the use of `-g` - then the debugger will know how to read that "`-g`" symbol information from the executable and cross-reference it with the core.  This means you can see the proper names of variables and functions in your stack frames, get line numbers and see the source as you step around in the executable.

That debug information is useful whenever debugging - whether you started with a core or just the executable alone.  It even helps produce better output from commands like [`pstack`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pstack+1).

Note that your environment may have other settings to control whether cores are generated (they can be big, and there's no general way to know if/when they can be removed, so they're not always wanted).  For example, on UNIX/LINUX shells it's often [`ulimit -c`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2919398/410767).

You may also be interested to read about [DWARF](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-dwarf-debug-format/index.html) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) - a commonly used debugging information format for encoding the embedded debug/symbol information in executable/library objects (e.g. on UNIX and Linux).

UPDATE per Victor's request in comments...

*Symbol information* lists identifiers from the source code (usually only after any [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) needed), the (virtual) memory addresses/offsets at which they'll be loaded in the process memory, the type (e.g. data vs. code).  For example...

```
$ cat ok.cc
int g_my_num;
namespace NS { int ns_my_num = 2; }
int f() { return g_my_num + NS::ns_my_num; }
int main() { return f(); }

$ g++ -g ok.cc -o ok    # compile ok executable with symbol info

$ nm ok    # show mangled identifiers
00000000004017c8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000401960 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000400478 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
000000000040037c T _Z1fv                     # this is f()
0000000000401798 D _ZN2NS9ns_my_numE         # this is NS::ns_my_num
00000000004017a8 d __CTOR_END__
00000000004017a0 d __CTOR_LIST__
00000000004017b8 d __DTOR_END__
00000000004017b0 d __DTOR_LIST__
0000000000400540 r __FRAME_END__
00000000004017c0 d __JCR_END__
00000000004017c0 d __JCR_LIST__
00000000004017c8 d __TMC_END__
00000000004017c8 d __TMC_LIST__
0000000000401980 A __bss_start
0000000000401788 D __data_start
0000000000400440 t __do_global_ctors_aux
00000000004002e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000401790 d __dso_handle
0000000000000000 a __fini_array_end
0000000000000000 a __fini_array_start
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000000 a __init_array_end
0000000000000000 a __init_array_start
00000000004003a0 T __libc_csu_fini
00000000004003b0 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
0000000000000000 a __preinit_array_end
0000000000000000 a __preinit_array_start
0000000000401980 A _edata
0000000000401994 A _end
0000000000400494 T _fini
000000000040047c T _init
0000000000400220 T _start
000000000040024c t call_gmon_start
0000000000401980 b completed.6118
0000000000401788 W data_start
0000000000400270 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000401988 b dtor_idx.6120
0000000000401994 A end
0000000000400350 t frame_dummy
0000000000401990 B g_my_num                   # our global g_my_num
0000000000400390 T main                       # the int main() function
00000000004002a0 t register_tm_clones

$ nm ok | c++filt            # c++filt "unmangles" identifiers...
00000000004017c8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000401960 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000400478 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
000000000040037c T f()
0000000000401798 D NS::ns_my_num
00000000004017a8 d __CTOR_END__
00000000004017a0 d __CTOR_LIST__
00000000004017b8 d __DTOR_END__
00000000004017b0 d __DTOR_LIST__
0000000000400540 r __FRAME_END__
00000000004017c0 d __JCR_END__
00000000004017c0 d __JCR_LIST__
00000000004017c8 d __TMC_END__
00000000004017c8 d __TMC_LIST__
0000000000401980 A __bss_start
0000000000401788 D __data_start
0000000000400440 t __do_global_ctors_aux
00000000004002e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000401790 d __dso_handle
0000000000000000 a __fini_array_end
0000000000000000 a __fini_array_start
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000000 a __init_array_end
0000000000000000 a __init_array_start
00000000004003a0 T __libc_csu_fini
00000000004003b0 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
0000000000000000 a __preinit_array_end
0000000000000000 a __preinit_array_start
0000000000401980 A _edata
0000000000401994 A _end
0000000000400494 T _fini
000000000040047c T _init
0000000000400220 T _start
000000000040024c t call_gmon_start
0000000000401980 b completed.6118
0000000000401788 W data_start
0000000000400270 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000401988 b dtor_idx.6120
0000000000401994 A end
0000000000400350 t frame_dummy
0000000000401990 B g_my_num
0000000000400390 T main
00000000004002a0 t register_tm_clones
```

Notes:

- our functions `f()` and `main()` are type `T` (which stands for "TEXT" - used for read-only non-zero memory content whether it's actually text or other data or executable code),
- `g_my_num` is `B` being a global with implicitly zero-ed out memory, while
- `NS::ns_my_num` is `D` as the executable has to explicitly provide the value `2` to occupy that memory.

The [man/info-page for `nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) documents these things further....

Comment: Note: the `strip` utility performs the reverse operation, ie it takes a library with debugging symbols and strip them off.

Comment: What is symbol information? Can you make this answer a little more ELIF for me please?

Comment: @TonyD Sorry about that. It stands for explain like I'm five. I haven't taken a compiler's course yet so I don't have that vocabulary.

Comment: @VictorLin: there's way too much involved here to explain it at that level - it would rapidly explode into explanations of addresses vs. offsets, "virtual" memory, Operating System loaders, etc. but I've given some basic details and an example - hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

The -g flag tells the compiler to generate debugging information. It has no impact on whether or not a core file will be generated. On most unix-like systems, that can be setup using the ulimit command.

Comment: but i want to know what exactly is that debugging information.i know waht you know already.i needed something which is beyond that.

Comment: @wvwvwv Beyound that, it's complicated - a thorough description takes a few dozen pages. You could start by looking at the DWARF (http://dwarfstd.org/Download.php) standard, which is the specification for the debugging symbols that are embedded within the executable(on most *nixes). -g instructs the compiler/linker to generate and embed these structures in the executable. The next step is probably understanding how a debugger uses this debugging information.

Comment: In short, it adds information about symbol names (functions, local and global variables etc) as well as information about types, source file names and line numbers. It might also via an automatically defined macro pull in different header files (ie for STL, and the definition of the assert macro) that ease debugging. It will probably also generate special output for inlined functions, so that stepping into inlined functions/methods is possible.

Answer (score 7):

The gcc -g flag tells gcc to generate and embed debug information. `ulimit -c` is used to enable core file generation. You can have either of these without the other.

Answer (score 3):

`-g` adds debugging information (variable names, line numbers etc) to the executable file.  It's part of what you need to do to be able to make sense of the core file.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options

Answer (score 2):

If you don't put -g flag, cannot call list in gdb to list what the source code looks like. it will show "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command."

Also if you type info func or info frame, info locals in gdb, without -g it will not show return datatype and its arguments, basically no translation of instruction to variable (mapping from symbol table).

Answer (score 1):

core file is generated on Segmentation Fault or such exceptions.  `gdb source.cc core` is one way to look into the core file.  Backtrace and investigating every frame is a start at looking into the core.  `-g` adds debugging symbols in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

core dump is one of a process´s default actions, when this process receives the signals, e.g. in the standard signals "SIGQUIT", "SIGILL", "SIGABRT", "SIGFPE", "SIGSEGV". However, most shells suppress the creation of core file, simply because the core files tend to be large and it can take some time or a lot of time.

in order to enable the core generation, "ulimit" is the utility that you can use to set the shell or its children process´s file limit.

compiler flags "-g" or whatever only concern with compiler. logically speaking, it has nothing to do with core dump.