# For running C code in linux what does `gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra` means?

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, compilation, compiler-options

These will be the flags used to run my code, I am a beginner in C and don't know what each one is used for. The code I must write for this is basically a string manipulation. Wonder if there is a website that gets many flags together?

```
gcc -g -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment: *Wonder if there is a website*. Yes, it's called the [gcc user manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html).

Comment: when in doubt about any Linux commands run `command --help` or `man command`. In this case run `gcc --help`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc` - the compiler program
`-g` - makes it easier / possible to debug the program in a debugger such as `gdb` - read more [about it in another StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179202/gcc-g-what-will-happen)
`-lm` - link to the library `libm` (the math library)
`-std=c99` - use the C standard from 1999
`-Wall` - enables all warnings about constructions that some user consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid
`-Wextra` - enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by `-Wall`

You can read more about GCC warnings [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: and after debugging `-O2` or `-O3` must be used

Comment: Except `-Wall` doesn't actually enable all warnings. `-Wall` = a fistful of warnings, `-Wextra` = a few warnings more.