# Attaching GDB to a dying process in linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, gdb, pyside

I would like to attach gdb to a dying process, because the program runs in production and I need to debug it there, if I open the program with gdb it slows down and the computers are not that great. I tried to catch signals in the application and attach gdb there but it just works if I send them signals myself. When the program stalls (multi-threaded program, and the main thread gets a deadlock or somehow gets stuck (or apparently stuck)), and the user forces it to quit in the Desktop Environment (LXDE), I can't catch no signal. The program is all python with PySide for the graphical interface. Just care about linux. 
My idea is to create a kernel driver and try too hook process termination or signals sending in there but since it would be much of a hassle I would like to ask if there is some tool for this kind of thing or some information that I could make use of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to do what you want, but if you can't perhaps it would be sufficient to freeze the program and inspect its memory image?

[Enable core dump file generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919378/how-to-enable-core-dump-in-my-linux-c-program) before it starts, and then once the process is hosed, terminate it with kill.  Then use gdb to open the [core file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core) and analyze what was happening.

Comment: What I'm trying to solve is when it gets stuck for the user (basically the main thread gets a deadlock or infinite loop or something) so what I'm doing now is to tell the user to call me so I can make a coredump at that point. I can create a button for them to click when the program gets stuck and then do the kill there, it works, I've tried, but it brings aditional problems because I have the program distributed in several places and it is a bit of a hassle in terms of managing the users and not disrupting the normal functioning of its usage.